# Возможно ли преобразовать дату вида "юникс таймштамп" из бд в удобный формат посредством API не выше 21?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Cохраняю дату в БД в виде тайм штампа одним числом, далее получаю её в коде приложения и хочу  привести например к виду "yyyy - MM - dd". Пытаюсь через `SimpleDateFormat`, но он требует API 24 и выше. Возможно ли как то получить читаемый формат даты посредством API 21 ? 
дату храню используя `long`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Класс `SimpleDateFormat` существует (как минимум) в двух пакетах:

1. `java.text` – доступен с API level 1;
2. `android.icu.text` – доступен с API level 24.

Для Ваших целей вполне подойдет класс из пакета `java.text`. Просто поменяйте импорт.

Comment: Спасибо большущее!!! все заработало